# Small space (indent) after `strip` environment

Tags: two-column, cuted

I use the `strip` environment of the [`cuted`](http://texcatalogue.sarovar.org/entries/cuted.html) package to add one column material (equations etc...) in a onecolumn box embedded in twocolumn text.

Well to be exact, I'd like to use it for that but there's a small bug that annoys me. When I use the environment just like any other environment there's a small space added in the beginning of the line *after* the `strip` environment.

Let me show you my MWE and the result (long line is just the rest of `lorem ipsum` no need to scroll right):

```tex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{cuted}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec hendrerit tempor tellus. Donec pretium posuere tellus. Proin quam nisl, tincidunt et, mattis eget, convallis nec, purus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus     mus. Nulla posuere. Donec vitae dolor. Nullam tristique diam non turpis. Cras placerat accumsan nulla. Nullam rutrum. Nam vestibulum accumsan nisl.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec hendrerit tempor tellus. Donec pretium posuere tellus. Proin quam nisl, tincidunt et, mattis eget, convallis nec, purus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus     mus. Nulla posuere. Donec vitae dolor. Nullam tristique diam non turpis. Cras placerat accumsan nulla. Nullam rutrum. Nam vestibulum accumsan nisl.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec hendrerit tempor tellus. Donec pretium posuere tellus. Proin quam nisl, tincidunt et, mattis eget, convallis nec, purus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus     mus. Nulla posuere. Donec vitae dolor. Nullam tristique diam non turpis. Cras placerat accumsan nulla. Nullam rutrum. Nam vestibulum accumsan nisl.
\begin{strip}
    \textbf{The quick brown fox...}
\end{strip}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec hendrerit tempor tellus. Donec pretium posuere tellus. Proin quam nisl, tincidunt et, mattis eget, convallis nec, purus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus     mus. Nulla posuere. Donec vitae dolor. Nullam tristique diam non turpis. Cras placerat accumsan nulla. Nullam rutrum. Nam vestibulum accumsan nisl.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec hendrerit tempor tellus. Donec pretium posuere tellus. Proin quam nisl, tincidunt et, mattis eget, convallis nec, purus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus     mus. Nulla posuere. Donec vitae dolor. Nullam tristique diam non turpis. Cras placerat accumsan nulla. Nullam rutrum. Nam vestibulum accumsan nisl.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec hendrerit tempor tellus. Donec pretium posuere tellus. Proin quam nisl, tincidunt et, mattis eget, convallis nec, purus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus     mus. Nulla posuere. Donec vitae dolor. Nullam tristique diam non turpis. Cras placerat accumsan nulla. Nullam rutrum. Nam vestibulum accumsan nisl.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec hendrerit tempor tellus. Donec pretium posuere tellus. Proin quam nisl, tincidunt et, mattis eget, convallis nec, purus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus     mus. Nulla posuere. Donec vitae dolor. Nullam tristique diam non turpis. Cras placerat accumsan nulla. Nullam rutrum. Nam vestibulum accumsan nisl.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec hendrerit tempor tellus. Donec pretium posuere tellus. Proin quam nisl, tincidunt et, mattis eget, convallis nec, purus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus     mus. Nulla posuere. Donec vitae dolor. Nullam tristique diam non turpis. Cras placerat accumsan nulla. Nullam rutrum. Nam vestibulum accumsan nisl.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec hendrerit tempor tellus. Donec pretium posuere tellus. Proin quam nisl, tincidunt et, mattis eget, convallis nec, purus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus     mus. Nulla posuere. Donec vitae dolor. Nullam tristique diam non turpis. Cras placerat accumsan nulla. Nullam rutrum. Nam vestibulum accumsan nisl.

\end{document}
```

With the result:

[image: ResultWithIndent]

Note the small space before the "Lorem" just after the `strip` environment. If I add a comment sign right after `\end{strip}` or move the `Lorem` just after `\end{strip}`, i.e. if I do either the replacement

```tex
\end{strip}%
  Lorem [...]
```

or

```tex
\end{strip}Lorem [...]
```

suddenly the space vanishes, i.e. compilation yields:

[image: ResultNoSpace]

I have set `\parindent` to zero to ensure that it isn't involved but for now I all out of possible solutions...

Do you have any suggestions/solutions? Thanks for helping!

Comment: In my version, (1) the code does not compile as is, I have to add empty line before `\begin{cuted}`, and (2) there's no spurious `\ ` in the first paragraph after `\end{cuted}`, and if there's for you, just add an empty line after `\end{cuted}`.

Comment: The environment's name is `strip` (see above), not `cuted` [but I guess that's just a typo and not wrong in the code you used, right?]. Well for _me_ it works without the empty line **before** the environment, I'm using `cuted` "v1.5 from 2012/10/04". Adding an empty line **after** the environment indeed removes the space just before `Lorem`, **however**, the empty line isn't mirrored in the right column, i.e. the top-alignment of the columns **after** the environment is not correct.

Comment: Sorry, I had an old version of that package. I posted a answer based on the up-to-date version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty line before `\begin{strip}` is **necessary**. If you looked into the log file, you would see there many badbox warnings that show that something is seriously wrong in the case you omit it:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 1377) in paragraph at lines 14--17
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 pretium po-suere tel-lus. Proin quam nisl, tin-

Underfull \hbox (badness 2111) in paragraph at lines 14--17
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 turpis. Cras plac-erat ac-cum-san nulla. Nul-

Underfull \hbox (badness 2237) in paragraph at lines 14--17
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 lam rutrum. Nam vestibu-lum ac-cum-san nisl.

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 14--17


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 14--17


Underfull \vbox (badness 1297) has occurred while \output is active [1{/usr/loc
al/texlive/2010/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux)
```

The following code produces a correct output. Output of `\listfiles`:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   cuted.sty    2012/10/04 v1.5 Mixing onecolumn and twocolumn modes
 ***********
```

[image]

```
\listfiles

\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{cuted}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec hendrerit tempor tellus. Donec pretium posuere tellus. Proin quam nisl, tincidunt et, mattis eget, convallis nec, purus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus     mus. Nulla posuere. Donec vitae dolor. Nullam tristique diam non turpis. Cras placerat accumsan nulla. Nullam rutrum. Nam vestibulum accumsan nisl.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec hendrerit tempor tellus. Donec pretium posuere tellus. Proin quam nisl, tincidunt et, mattis eget, convallis nec, purus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus     mus. Nulla posuere. Donec vitae dolor. Nullam tristique diam non turpis. Cras placerat accumsan nulla. Nullam rutrum. Nam vestibulum accumsan nisl.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec hendrerit tempor tellus. Donec pretium posuere tellus. Proin quam nisl, tincidunt et, mattis eget, convallis nec, purus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus     mus. Nulla posuere. Donec vitae dolor. Nullam tristique diam non turpis. Cras placerat accumsan nulla. Nullam rutrum. Nam vestibulum accumsan nisl.

\begin{strip}
    \textbf{The quick brown fox...}
\end{strip}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec hendrerit tempor tellus. Donec pretium posuere tellus. Proin quam nisl, tincidunt et, mattis eget, convallis nec, purus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus     mus. Nulla posuere. Donec vitae dolor. Nullam tristique diam non turpis. Cras placerat accumsan nulla. Nullam rutrum. Nam vestibulum accumsan nisl.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec hendrerit tempor tellus. Donec pretium posuere tellus. Proin quam nisl, tincidunt et, mattis eget, convallis nec, purus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus     mus. Nulla posuere. Donec vitae dolor. Nullam tristique diam non turpis. Cras placerat accumsan nulla. Nullam rutrum. Nam vestibulum accumsan nisl.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec hendrerit tempor tellus. Donec pretium posuere tellus. Proin quam nisl, tincidunt et, mattis eget, convallis nec, purus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus     mus. Nulla posuere. Donec vitae dolor. Nullam tristique diam non turpis. Cras placerat accumsan nulla. Nullam rutrum. Nam vestibulum accumsan nisl.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec hendrerit tempor tellus. Donec pretium posuere tellus. Proin quam nisl, tincidunt et, mattis eget, convallis nec, purus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus     mus. Nulla posuere. Donec vitae dolor. Nullam tristique diam non turpis. Cras placerat accumsan nulla. Nullam rutrum. Nam vestibulum accumsan nisl.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec hendrerit tempor tellus. Donec pretium posuere tellus. Proin quam nisl, tincidunt et, mattis eget, convallis nec, purus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus     mus. Nulla posuere. Donec vitae dolor. Nullam tristique diam non turpis. Cras placerat accumsan nulla. Nullam rutrum. Nam vestibulum accumsan nisl.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec hendrerit tempor tellus. Donec pretium posuere tellus. Proin quam nisl, tincidunt et, mattis eget, convallis nec, purus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus     mus. Nulla posuere. Donec vitae dolor. Nullam tristique diam non turpis. Cras placerat accumsan nulla. Nullam rutrum. Nam vestibulum accumsan nisl.

\end{document}
```